Replace path in the Ingress k8s with traefik
I'm using Ingress (with traefik) to map my scorpio backend using:
- backend:
    service:
      name: scorpio
      port: 
        number: 9090
  path: /ngsi-ld
  pathType: Prefix 

and I can access it successfully via http://myservice.com/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=data.
I have to replace /ngsi-ld with /api in the external URL path: i.e. http://myservice.com/api/v1/entities?type=data.
In this case, I have to use path: /api but the call provide me 404 because the server scorpio uses ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=data
and I don't know how to build the Ingress.
I also tried unsuccessfully using rewrite-target annotation and pathType ImplementationSpecific as follows:
annotations    
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true

and paths:
  path: /api(/|$)(.*)
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific

Please, could you help me?

If possible can you update the question with the full configuration file? Please refer to the Rewrite-target for additional information

I tried a lot of configurations

I solved my problem: I used a Middleware k8s resource as follow:
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: replace-api-with-ngsi-ld
  namespace: default  
spec:
  replacePathRegex:
    regex: "^/api(.*)"
    replacement: "/ngsi-ld$1"

then I had to add in my Ingress the annotation: traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-replace-api-with-ngsi-ld@kubernetescrd and set:
- backend:
    service:
      name: scorpio
      port: 
        number: 9090
  path: /api
  pathType: Prefix

